# PC won't boot with USBs plugged in

Tags: windows-xp, boot, freeze, thinkpad

Yesterday as I was shutting down my computer (Thinkpad t-60) the computer froze during shut down on the "Windows is shutting down" screen.

When I went to reboot it, it froze at the 1st, "welcome to Thinkpad screen, and would not reboot.

My tech informed me that sometimes this happened due to USBs, and when I boot with none attached, it boots. When I plug everything back in it works, and the machine shut down this time with everything plugged in. However, when I re-booted, same thing, so I had to unplug the USBs and reboot.

When it re-booted, Outlook said it hadn't closed properly and went through the procedure to boot. I had closed Outlook previous to shutting down. I'm not sure if these are related.

Can anyone tell me how to fix the boot problem?
Thanks,

Comment: Try isolating which device is causing the problem by booting with just attaching a single USB device

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove any and all USB devices from the boot priority list, and you can still encounter this issue.  Your technician was correct.  I know of at least one desktop motherboard, an Asus M3N78, that functioned perfectly with the exception that if anything was plugged into one of the USB ports, the machine would not boot.  Didn't matter if it was a drive or a usb network card, or even a USB gameport joystick converter.  In this particular case, any device accessing the 5v power through any USB hub on that boar would cause it not to boot.  I'm not talking about the BIOS loading and locking up.  I'm talking the unit would not power on until the USB device was removed.

Since yours is locking up during the boot process, it definitely does seem to be a BIOS issue, as the BIOS is attempting to determine exactly what is plugged into the port, but can't and is getting stuck at that point.

You could flash your BIOS to the most recent version.  You could see if it is one particular device that is causing the machine to lock up, by not plugging them ALL in, but instead just plugging one in and turning the unit on.

Lastly, try removing the USB CD player entirely. It just may not be working.

Comment: How do I flash my bios?

Comment: Follow this link to the T60 product page http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=MIGR-62487 and click the Drivers and Software link.  Follow the onscreen instructions to specifically identify your exact model.  Download the latest BIOS from Lenovo/IBM and follow their instructions to update your BIOS.

Comment: +1. Thanks. I won't be able to test until tomorrow, but I flashed the Bios.

Comment: I flashed the Bios - no joy. Nothing changed.

Comment: Well, That most likely ruled out it being a BIOS issue.  So, at this point it looks like it is either one of the devices you are plugging into the ports, or damage to the motherboard (or ports... I consider these to be the same for the purpose of this discussion).  So, as has been suggested, start testing.  Plug one of the devices in, and boot.  If it locks, unplug that, turn it off, plug a different device in and boot.  Test each, one at a time.

Comment: @random I didn't know he had a USB CD player... the question only mentions "with everything plugged in" and "unplug the USBs" and I didn't see any mention in his comments as to what these devices were... that's why I never mentioned them in my original answer.

Comment: OP added it in themselves, and just added on to make it more comprehensive

Comment: Got it.  Cool.  I was wondering what the devices were that he had been connecting.

Comment: I've seen the problem of boards that won't boot with a USB device plugged in but in every case I've isolated it to the USB device feeding power back into the board.  Devices completely incapable of feeding power backwards would not cause a problem.  One board in question had one of those I'm-hot lights and that would illuminate when the offending USB devices were plugged in even if the power supply was unplugged.

Answer (score 2):

Almost sounds like your system is looking at the USB as a boot device on start up. If you are famililar with the bios screen ** Check the boot priority and make sure that your hard drive is the first boot device to possibly eliminate the problems you are having.

**On restart it is F1 to enter the BIOS on a ThinkPad**

Comment: when I go to BIOS, I can find no way to check the order of boot. I always was able to on my previous machines. There is just no mention of start up order.

Comment: @Xavierjazz On a T60, enter bios, go to ">Startup" then ">Boot", set the priority in there, set "ATA HDD0" to the top of the list #1, save changes on exit.

Comment: @Xavierjazz Enter the bios, hit F9 to load defaults, then F10 to save and exit, re enter the bios and be sure HDD0 is still first boot device, see if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

My BIOS had a bug that it wouldn't boot if an NTFS-formatted drive was plugged in the USB.
I took ages to fix this problem because I always thought to be an OS problem, or something else.

Or maybe it's searching for a boot partition from the USB