# USB not recognized

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, usb

When I plug in `External USB mass storage device`, the following error message is displayed:
[image: USB ERROR]

Previously the device was working correctly, but after few months when I plug it in, it is not working. I have found [USB device not recognized](https://superuser.com/questions/348432/usb-device-not-recognized), but it does not solve my problem.

NOTE: Some other USB mass storage devices are detected, but with one of my devices I get this error message. Can this be problem with my device? Does a device become malfunctioned automatically by not using it for sometime?

Comment: When I normally get this it's because the device actually is malfunctioning... Just because it did work does not mean it still works.

Comment: No, an USB device doesn't go bad due to lack-of-use or "sitting around", but it could've gone bad for many other reasons.  Unfortunately, you don't include what type of device it is, so it's hard to even try to provide any of the reasons this might happen, except in the most general way.